# Trying to display 06:00 the hour and minute from an array

Tags: java, arrays, datetime

I'm trying to display the time a car parks in a parking lot but its not displaying right example(
Car with license aaaaaa parked at 6:0) but i need it to display (06:00) and If im using the array right for the time  separating it from hours and minutes because the user also tell what they departure from the parking lot and pay  a fee in minutes

```
   public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String code = " ";
        String sentinel = "Q";
        
        Stack<Vehicle> parkingLot = new Stack<>();
        ArrayList<Vehicle> temporarilyParking = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        while(!code.equalsIgnoreCase(sentinel))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter code (A for Arrival, D for Departure, Q to quit): ");
            code = scan.nextLine();
            
            switch(code.toUpperCase()) {
                case "A": 
                    System.out.print("Enter license : ");
                    String license = scan.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter time (hh:mm):");
                    String time = scan.nextLine();
                    String []timeArray;
                    timeArray = time.split(":");
                    int hour = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[0]);
                    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[1]);
                    
                    System.out.println("Car with license " + license + " parked at " + hour + ":" + minutes);
                    break;
            }
                
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Hello! I can't help but notice this looks like homework. What have you tried? 

I see your PrintLine is returning a string with some numbers in it. If only there was a way to FORMAT the numbers inside the string.

For figuring out your fee you have the hours and the minutes in integer form right there. You should convert them all to minutes and then multiply by the fee per minute value where ever that is.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: Consider `parkingLot.push(new Vehicle(license, LocalTime.parse(time)));` It will make your time ops easier probably

Answer (score 0):

You need a [formatted string](https://www.baeldung.com/string/format), using `%02d` to display an integer of width 2 that is left padded with zeroes:

```
System.out.format("Car with license %s parked at %02d:%02d\n", license, hour, minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use System.out.printf()

```
System.out.print("Enter license : ");
String license = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter time (hh:mm):");
String time = scan.nextLine();
String[] timeArray = time.split(":");
int hour = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[0]);
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[1]);
                    
System.out.printf("Car with license %s parked at %02d:%02d", license, hour, minutes);
```

But in your solution, you may print the String **time** straight away since you already request input in the format **hh:mm**

```
System.out.print("Enter license : ");
String license = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter time (hh:mm):");
String time = scan.nextLine();
System.out.printf("Car with license %s parked at %s", license, time);

// for calculation
String[] timeArray = time.split(":");
int hour = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[0]);
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[1]);
```